# C++ SDL2 Text Renderer with the error: access violation reading location

Tags: c++, c++17, runtime-error, access-violation, text-rendering

I'm currently trying to create a game in C++17 with SDL2 (and SDL_ttf). When I'm trying to initialize the text renderer, I'm getting an error that says: "Exception thrown at 0x00007FFFB5A19116 (SDL2_ttf.dll) in projVSC.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000060." Currently using Visual Studio Community 2022.
I'm getting the error in two places:

1. The game.cpp file:

```
void Game::init()
{
    if (SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(1280, 720, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE, &window, &renderer) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Window and Render could not be created! SDL_Error: " << SDL_GetError() << '\n';
        isRunning = false;
        return;
    }
    textRenderer = new TextRenderer(renderer, "PlayfairDisplayRegular-ywLOY.ttf", 24);
    if (!textRenderer) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create text renderer." << std::endl;
        isRunning = false;
        return;
    }
    SDL_SetWindowTitle(window, "projVSC");
    isRunning = true;
}
```

and 2. the TextRenderer.cpp file:

```
#include "TextRenderer.h"
#include <iostream>

TextRenderer::TextRenderer(SDL_Renderer* renderer, const std::string& fontPath, int fontSize) : renderer(renderer), font(nullptr) {
    font = TTF_OpenFont(fontPath.c_str(), fontSize);
    if (!font) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to load font: " << TTF_GetError() << std::endl;
        // Handle error (e.g., exit or throw an exception)
    }
}

TextRenderer::~TextRenderer() {
    if (font != nullptr) {
        TTF_CloseFont(font);
    }
}

void TextRenderer::renderText(const std::string& text, int x, int y, SDL_Color color) {
    SDL_Surface* surface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, text.c_str(), color);
    if (!surface) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to render text: " << TTF_GetError() << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, surface);
    SDL_Rect renderQuad = { x, y, surface->w, surface->h };

    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, nullptr, &renderQuad);

    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
}
```

Initially the issue was it being unable to find the .ttf file, which resulted in the text renderer defaulting to the nullptr it's set as. I was able to get it to recognize the proper location of it, but while my checks no longer say it's passing a nullptr in the debugging output, It's still not able to read the text file, with the error given before, "Exception thrown at 0x00007FFFB5A19116 (SDL2_ttf.dll) in projVSC.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000060." This is my first attempt at making a game, so hopefully someone can give some insight^^.

Comment: What do you mean you are getting the error in two places? The exact same error in two places is a bit strange. The first thing I would do is, in the debugger, when the exception is thrown, examine the *call stack* and see the place where you left your code and entered the SDL library code (which is where the exception is actually thrown). That should give a big clue as to the cause. Try that and report back what you find.

Comment: I wonder if the exception is not happening on the main thread. That would explain why it seems to pop up in different locations. But again the debugger should tell you if that is the case.